# Image is not getting drawn at the specific point index

Tags: java, drawimage

I am trying to make a GUI program where there is an array of points and an image should be repainted at the specific point or index.The code is below:-

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Trial {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    public JButton button;

    Trial(){        

        Point[] array = new Point[5];
            array[0] = new Point(150,200);

        button = new JButton("Paste");
                button.setBounds(875, 525, 125, 50);

        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\GUI Program\\src\\com\\company\\Square.PNG"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        java.awt.Graphics g = getGraphics();
                        g.drawImage(image, array[0].x, array[0].y, null);
                    }); 
        }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Trial trialObject = new Trial();
    }
}
```

The image is not being drawn at the point. Please help me draw the image at the specific index.

I am still a beginner programmer. So any answer would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code won't even compile. You need a frame in which to put the button and image. I suggest that you find a good book or online tutorial for beginners. Also, AWT is outdated. Consider using Swing or JavaFX. Here's Oacles tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Actually this isnt my real code, i was just trying to make a minimal reproducible example. In my real code, i have already done everything related to JFrame and all. But still there is the same problem

Comment: @camickr, ur answer may solve the problem, but another thing is that i also want to remove or erase the image from its previous position. U can think this as moving an image to another point but instead of moving, just teleporting it there with a button click

Comment: @ShubhamGoel, You change the Point object in your custom object to the images new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom `JPanel` for the custom painting and then override the `paintComponent()` method to do the painting. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for some basics.

> there is an array of points and an image should be repainted at the specific point

You should create a custom object that contains all the information needed to the the painting. So in your case you would need two properties:

1. the Point
2. the Image

You store this custom object in an ArrayList. So your class will need an `addCustomObject(...)` method to add each object to the ArrayList.

Then in the `paintComponent()` method you iterate through the `ArrayList` and paint each object using the properties of the object.

Check out the `Draw On Component` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: As i am not much experienced in java, i am finding it difficult to do what u have said. So could u also include a trial code in ur answer telling everything i need to do.

Comment: *So could u also include a trial codei* - I did include trial code. The link provided a working example that used a custom class with a Color and a Rectangle instead of a Point and an Image. Only you know your exact requirement. So download the code and play with it and then customize it for your exact requirement.  If you have specific questions about that code then I can help. We are not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a JFrame and JPanel and draw the image inside of it

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.drawImage(image, array[0].x, array[0].y, null);
    }
};
f.add(p);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) Don't override paint(). In Swing you override `paintComponent(...)` 2) the first statement should be `super.paintComponent(g)` to make sure the background is cleared.

Comment: @camickr thank you for your comment can you please explain to me the different between paint() and paintComponent()

Comment: In my answer I provided a link to the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting` that goes into more detail about the painting process in Swing.